# How to apply pinch zoom and rotation on stickerView?

Tags: android, android-layout, multi-touch

I am working on android **`stickerview`** using [**this library**](https://github.com/nimengbo/StickerView). i have some customization but stuck in following method.

when i try to zoom-in zoom-out it will not properly work.
and when i try to rotate from full view (multi-touch) it also not working.
using multitouch this method executed here i want pinching functionily and rotation while single touch working fine 
Here Method

**For Multi-Touch**

```
            float disNew = spacing(event);
            if (disNew == 0 || disNew < pointerLimitDis) {
                scale = 1;
            } else {
                scale = disNew / oldDis;

                scale = (scale - 1) * pointerZoomCoeff + 1;
            }
            float scaleTemp = (scale * Math.abs(dst_flipV.left - dst_resize.left)) / oringinWidth;
            if (((scaleTemp <= MIN_SCALE)) && scale < 1 ||
                    (scaleTemp >= MAX_SCALE) && scale > 1) {
                scale = 1;
            } else {
                lastLength = diagonalLength(event);
            }
            matrix.postScale(scale, scale, mid.x, mid.y);
            invalidate();
```

**For Single Touch**

```
matrix.postRotate((rotationToStartPoint(event) - lastRotateDegree) * 2, mid.x, mid.y);
                    lastRotateDegree = rotationToStartPoint(event);

                    float scales = diagonalLength(event) / lastLength;

                    if (((diagonalLength(event) / halfDiagonalLength <= MIN_SCALE)) && scales < 1 ||
                            (diagonalLength(event) / halfDiagonalLength >= MAX_SCALE) && scales > 1) {
                        scales = 1;
                        if (!isInResize(event)) {
                            isInResize = false;
                        }
                    } else {
                        lastLength = diagonalLength(event);
                    }
                    matrix.postScale(scales, scales, mid.x, mid.y);
                    invalidate();
```

[**Library For StickerView**](https://github.com/nimengbo/StickerView)
[image]